# htaccess rewriting - include subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in a htaccess file placed in the root of my domain:

```
RewriteRule ^t-shirt-A([^/]+)/([^.]+)$ /tshirt.php?t=t-shirt-A$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I'm trying to modify it to apply the rewrite even if there is a subdomain. Problem is that the htaccess will be used on a couple of different websites, so the subdomain AND domain name can vary so it can't be hardcoded.

For example, i would want to rewrite these url

> http://www.any_domain_name_here.com/t-shirt-A123456789
>   http://any_subdomain.another_domain_name_here.com/t-shirt-A987654321

to:

> http://www.any_domain_name_here.com/t-shirt.php?t=t-shirt-A123456789
>   http://any_subdomain.another_domain_name_here.com/t-shirt.php?t=t-shirt-A123456789

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't seem right for matching `/t-shirt-A123456789`:

Try this rule in your `DcoumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(t-shirt[^/]+)/?$ /tshirt.php?t=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It will be applied to every domain that is using this `DcoumentRoot`

Comment: it will not work if i use http://subdomain.mydomain.com/t-shirtA123456789 :( Still only works for main domain root

Comment: In you examples you didn't have `/t-shirtA123456789` but I have edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, what i meant is that the rewriting is only working without using a subdomain (i only have the htaccess file in my root file and i can't copy it inside the subdomain's folder)

Comment: What is `DocumentRoot` of the subdomain set to? Is it same as main domain OR it is a sub directory under main domain's `DocumentRoot`

Comment: It is just a subdomain created through cPanel with default settings. So for example http://potatoes.mywebsite.com will use the source http://www.mywebsite.com/potatoes/

Comment: domain is running on HTTPS and subdomain is on HTTP maybe thats why ?

Comment: No it is not related to HTTP/HTTPS. Thing is that any domain can only be controlled by rule in it's `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` or level bwlow `DocumentRoot`. But in this case it seems your subdomain's `DocumentRoot` is `/potatoes` folder. It this case rewrite rule in parent of `/potatoes` won't be even read for subdomain. You can either cope main .htaccess OR create a symbolic link inside `/potatoes` folder